# How to run camera on page in preview mode?

Tags: camera, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I create an application for working with the camera, I just can not figure out how to call the camera, so that it was in preview mode.

In the documentation I read, there only a photo can be done, but you can not bring the camera to the page!
[cordova-plugin-camera](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)

There is an example of an application where the camera is displayed on the page in preview mode:

[image]

Here on the background of the page the camera is shown and it is possible to work with camera

Is there anyone among you who worked with the camera, if so, tell me how or give advice. Thank you!

Ps: sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/) plugin. It is built to display a camera preview in HTML. Please be aware that the authors of the plugin stated themselfes that the plugin is still *under constant development* so there might be some things that do not work as expected.

The plugin offers following features:

- Start a camera preview from HTML code.
- Maintain HTML interactivity.
- Drag the preview box.
- Set camera color effect.
- Send the preview box to back of the HTML content.
- Set a custom position for the camera preview box.
- Set a custom size for the preview box.
- Set a custom alpha for the preview box.
- Set the focus mode, zoom, color effects, exposure mode, white balance mode and exposure compensation
- Tap to focus